# Laravel Call to a member function toArray() on array Error

Tags: php, macos, laravel

I was hoping someone could possibly clear up a little confusion I've been having with this Error. So here is my code. (note) the User model has a hasMany relationship to Image

```
    $user = User::with('profile')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();

    $images = $user->images->all();

    dd($user->toArray());
```

My confusion is dd($user->toArray()); works perfectly fine. But when I try this dd($images->toArray()) I get a Call to a member function toArray() on array. This has been killing me for a while. $user and $images are both objects but toArray() only works on $user. Also, $images[0]->toArray() works fine too so that just adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this happens because $images is a collection of objects not an object like $user.
Check [querying-relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) in the documentation the red area in the end of that section. That explains why $images[0]->toArray() works fine.

Comment: Ah, Im digging into it a little deeper. $images being a collection makes sense. check and +1, thanks for you time.